# Synonymize [quaternion] and [quaternions]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request, synonym-request

The [quaternion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quaternion) and [quaternions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quaternions) tags are obvious synonyms, having 47 and 446 questions respectively.
Many of the questions are duplicated between the two tags.

Comment: I don't know... I am personally an expert in the single quaternion `1`. I can't do multiple quaternions however...

Comment: Why not keep only [tag:quaternion] and burn [tag:quaternions]?

Comment: The topic as a whole is usually referred to (in the literature) as "quaternions", so that would seem the more natural tag. This would also matche the existing practice with, for example "loop" (mapped to "loops") and "array" (mapped to "arrays").